# blender is not using 1050ti GPU for cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I have updated blender to 9.20 but after updating blender is not using 1050ti for cycles render. I have
configured it in preference and using experimental feature but still my GPU usage is 0% and CPU usage is 100%, however it was working well before updating.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your GPU is greyed out. What mode did you have selected in the Preferences when you too the screen grab of your Render settings? You will need to leave it on CUDA to have it active.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply it, solved my problem is solved. Can you tell me what Optix and openCL Do.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html